# How do I use ES2015 Proxy in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, proxy-classes

Since Meteor 1.2 ES2015 is supported by default for any .js file in a Meteor project. That's great, but when I try to use the name Proxy like

```
const p = new Proxy(obj1, obj2);
```

it throws an undefined name Proxy.

I know ES6 is supported as all other features work (including Promises). So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured it out.
Meteor uses Babel transpiler which doesn't offer support for Proxies, since it isn't possible to polyfill using ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do add the ecmascript package to your project?

```
meteor add ecmascript
```

It isn't native to 1.2; you still need to add it to your project.

Comment: Yeah, I did. Like I said, I use all other ES6 features, I just don't seem to be able to use that in particular. Maybe it's on a different name? I don't know, I can't find anything about it